# boost spirit reporting semantic error

Tags: c++, boost-spirit-qi

I am playing with boost.spirit library and I cannot manage to report a simple error message from my semantic action.

```
// supported parameter types (int or quoted strings)
parameter = bsqi::int_ | bsqi::lexeme[L'"' > *(bsqi_coding::char_ - L'"') > L'"'];
parameter.name("parameter");

// comma separator list of parameters (or no parameters)
parameters = -(parameter % L',');
parameters.name("parameters");

// action with parameters
action = (Actions > L'(' > parameters > L')')[bsqi::_pass = boost::phoenix::bind(&ValidateAction, bsqi::_1, bsqi::_2)];
action.name("action");
```

The `Actions` is just a symbol table (`boost::spirit::qi::symbols`). The attribute of `parameters` is `std::vector` of `boost::variant` which describes the parameters types. I would like to produces a meaningful error message within semantic action `ValidateAction` with also indicating position within input what is wrong. If I just assign `_pass` to false, parsing ends but the error message is something like 'expecting ' and not that e.g. 2nd parameter has wrong type (expected int instead of string).

Somewhere I read that I can throw an exception from my semantic action, but the problem is that I didn't find whether and how I can access iterators from parsed values. For example I wanted to use `expectation_failure` exception so my error handler automatically is called, but I need to pass iterators to the exception which seems impossible.

Is there any nice way how to report semantic failures with more detailed information except returning just false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use filepos_iterator and just throw an exception, so you have complete control over the reporting.

<strike>Let me see what I can come up with in the remaining 15 minutes I have</strike>

Ok, took a little bit more time but think it's an instructive demo:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3e1fe19b6d4cc10)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/support_line_pos_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_iter_pos.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace qr = boost::spirit::repository::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;
namespace qi_coding = boost::spirit::ascii;
using It = boost::spirit::line_pos_iterator<std::string::const_iterator>;

namespace ast {
    enum actionid { f_unary, f_binary };
    enum param_type { int_param, string_param };

    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, actionid id) {
        switch(id) {
            case f_unary:      return os << "f_unary";
            case f_binary:     return os << "f_binary";
            default:           return os << "(unknown)";
        } }
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, param_type t) {
        switch(t) {
            case int_param:    return os << "integer";
            case string_param: return os << "string";
            default:           return os << "(unknown)";
        } }


    using param_value = boost::variant<int, std::string>;
    struct parameter {
        It position;
        param_value value;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, parameter const& p) { return os << p.value; }
    };
    using parameters = std::vector<parameter>;

    struct action {
        /*
         *action() = default;
         *template <typename Sequence> action(Sequence const& seq) { boost::fusion::copy(seq, *this); }
         */
        actionid id;
        parameters params;
    };
}

namespace std {
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ast::parameters const& v) {
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<ast::parameter>(os, " "));
        return os;
    }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::action, id, params)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::parameter, position, value)

struct BadAction : std::exception {
    It          _where;
    std::string _what;
    BadAction(It it, std::string msg) : _where(it), _what(std::move(msg)) {}
    It where() const { return _where; }
    char const* what() const noexcept { return _what.c_str(); }
};

struct ValidateAction {
    std::map<ast::actionid, std::vector<ast::param_type> > const specs {
        { ast::f_unary,  { ast::int_param } },
        { ast::f_binary, { ast::int_param, ast::string_param } },
    };

    ast::action operator()(It source, ast::action parsed) const {
        auto check = [](ast::parameter const& p, ast::param_type expected_type) {
            if (p.value.which() != expected_type) {
                auto name = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(expected_type);
                throw BadAction(p.position, "Type mismatch (expecting " + name + ")");
            }
        };

        int i;
        try {
            auto& formals = specs.at(parsed.id);
            auto& actuals = parsed.params;
            auto  arity   = formals.size();

            for (i=0; i<arity; ++i)
                check(actuals.at(i), formals.at(i));

            if (actuals.size() > arity) 
                throw BadAction(actuals.at(arity).position, "Excess parameters");
        } catch(std::out_of_range const&) { 
            throw BadAction(source, "Missing parameter #" + std::to_string(i+1)); 
        }
        return parsed;
    }
};

template <typename It, typename Skipper = qi::space_type>
struct Parser : qi::grammar<It, ast::action(), Skipper> {
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;
        parameter  = qr::iter_pos >> (int_ | lexeme['"' >> *~qi_coding::char_('"') >> '"']);
        parameters = -(parameter % ',');
        action     = actions_ >> '(' >> parameters >> ')';
        start      = (qr::iter_pos >> action) [ _val = validate_(_1, _2) ];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((parameter)(parameters)(action))
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, ast::action(),     Skipper> start, action;
    qi::rule<It, ast::parameters(), Skipper> parameters;
    qi::rule<It, ast::parameter(),  Skipper> parameter;
    px::function<ValidateAction> validate_;

    struct Actions : qi::symbols<char, ast::actionid> {
        Actions() { this->add("f_unary", ast::f_unary)("f_binary", ast::f_binary); }
    } actions_;

};

int main() {
    for (std::string const input : {
            // good
            "f_unary( 0 )",
            "f_binary ( 47, \"hello\")",
            // errors
            "f_binary ( 47, \"hello\") bogus",
            "f_unary ( 47, \"hello\") ",
            "f_binary ( 47, \r\n      7) ",
        })
    {
        std::cout << "-----------------------\n";
        Parser<It> p;
        It f(input.begin()), l(input.end());

        auto printErrorContext = [f,l](std::ostream& os, It where) {
            auto line = get_current_line(f, where, l);

            os << " line:" << get_line(where) 
               << ", col:" << get_column(line.begin(), where) << "\n";
            while (!line.empty() && std::strchr("\r\n", *line.begin()))
                line.advance_begin(1);
            std::cerr << line << "\n";
            std::cerr << std::string(std::distance(line.begin(), where), ' ') << "^ --- here\n";
        };

        ast::action data;
        try {
            if (qi::phrase_parse(f, l, p > qi::eoi, qi::space, data)) {
                std::cout << "Parsed: " << boost::fusion::as_vector(data) << "\n";
            }
        } catch(qi::expectation_failure<It> const& e) {
            printErrorContext(std::cerr << "Expectation failed: " << e.what_, e.first);
        } catch(BadAction const& ba) {
            printErrorContext(std::cerr << "BadAction: " << ba.what(), ba.where());
        }

        if (f!=l) {
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Printing:

```
-----------------------
Parsed: (f_unary 0 )
-----------------------
Parsed: (f_binary 47 hello )
-----------------------
Expectation failed: <eoi> line:1, col:25
f_binary ( 47, "hello") bogus
                        ^ --- here
Remaining unparsed: 'f_binary ( 47, "hello") bogus'
-----------------------
BadAction: Excess parameters line:1, col:15
f_unary ( 47, "hello") 
              ^ --- here
Remaining unparsed: 'f_unary ( 47, "hello") '
-----------------------
BadAction: Type mismatch (expecting string) line:2, col:8
      7) 
      ^ --- here
Remaining unparsed: 'f_binary ( 47, 
      7) '
```

Comment: Only just managed to create a SSCCE from your sketch http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/YshtnalFMGZtzbAK - will come back to this later

Comment: The code looks very similar to mine. I already looked in `line_pos_iterator`, but it is just adaptor to another iterator. Regardless of iterator type, it is still necessary to access the instances or references to the iterators which then I can use to throw exceptions or format a message. In my case I have always a single line as input so calculating offset can be done directly with `std::distance(first, current)` but I didn't find how can I access `first` and `current` in semantic actions. I think using special iterators are not 100% required. I am looking forward for you answer.

Comment: Ok, presented without much explanation. If you have questions, I'll be around in about 4 hours. [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54cf7f41dce257b3)

Comment: Round 2, [cleanup](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40629539/revisions). Much saner code style now. No longer using `phoenix::bind`. I'm done for now. [Cheers.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3e1fe19b6d4cc10)

Comment: Cool, thx a lot. The trick is to add this `qr::iter_pos` to add iterator as attribute. In my code I also changed all bound attribute types (action and parameter in your code) to templates to accept any iterator and then using `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_TPL_STRUCT` (maybe it helps others who follow the discussion).