# passing a spirit parsed struct to a function using phoenix::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I'm updating some old code which worked under older (~1.38 or so) versions of boost.  I've updated to boost 1.63 and can not seem to figure out how to get the old version to compile.

This is the relevant parts

```
void print (StateStruct const& ss)
{
   std::cout << ss.Name;
}

struct StateStruct
{
  std::string Name;
  float avalue;
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT (
  StateStruct,
  (std::string, NAME)
  (float, avalue)
)
```

and the parser rule that used to work

```
state %=
( qi::lexeme[qi::char_(a-zA-Z) >> +qi::char("-a-zA-Z0-9_")]
 >> qi::float_
)
[phoenix::bind(&print, qi::_val)]
;

qi::rule (Iterator, StateStruct(), skipper_type) state;
```

With g++ 6.3.0 and boost 1.63 I get and error message along the lines of

invalid initialization of type `const StateStruct::StateStruct&` from expression of type `boost::fusion::vector<boost::fusion::vector<char, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > >, float>`

without the semantic action the code compiles and debugging the state rule shows the expected results.  What do I need to do to correctly initialize the struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree this looks like a regression, you may want to report it to the maintainers at the [spirit-general] mailing list.

On a hunch I remembered an obscure define that got introduced as some kind of a compatibility hack¹. Lo and behold, the thing compiles with `BOOST_SPIRIT_ACTIONS_ALLOW_ATTR_COMPAT` defined:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6590c70c655add0)</kbd>**:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_ACTIONS_ALLOW_ATTR_COMPAT
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

struct StateStruct { std::string Name; float avalue; };

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(StateStruct, Name, avalue)

void print(StateStruct const& ss) { std::cout << "print: " << ss.Name << "\n"; }

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

int main() {
    using Iterator = std::string::const_iterator;
    using skipper_type = qi::space_type;
    qi::rule<Iterator, StateStruct(), skipper_type> state;

    state %=
        ( qi::as_string [ qi::lexeme[qi::char_("a-zA-Z") >> +qi::char_("-a-zA-Z0-9_")] ] >> qi::float_
        )
        [ px::bind(&print, qi::_val) ]
        ;

    std::string const input("identifier31415 3.1415");
    Iterator f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
    StateStruct parsed;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, state, qi::space, parsed);

    if (ok)
        std::cout << "Parsed: " << boost::fusion::as_vector(parsed) << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

    if (f != l)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
}
```

Printing:

```
print: identifier31415
Parsed: (identifier31415 3.1415)
```

¹ (I think it got introduced to give some people a feature that could not be generally enabled because it would break existing code)

Comment: Sir you have saved me untold frustration.  Do you happen to remember where this is/was documented because I drew a blank from several days of searching.  As a note I apologize for not posting a full program.  The machine I'm working on is not able to connect to the internet.

Comment: I just remembered this rare thing on the mailing list. It's from 2011 http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/fusion-vector2-std-pair-compatibility-td3529649i20.html.

Comment: Just googling it again, turns out the docs make a mention of it as well http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/what_s_new/spirit_2_5.html#spirit.what_s_new.spirit_2_5.making_stuff_work. Also, see this 2016 answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40726982/85371 for other approaches

Comment: This mention from 2012 makes the interesting observation that [_"BOOST_SPIRIT_ACTIONS_ALLOW_ATTR_COMPAT is cool, but not defining it is sometimes even cooler. Because it allows the rule's attributes to be different from the attributes synthesized by the parser"_](https://sourceforge.net/p/spirit/mailman/message/29627088/)

Comment: Thanks,  I'll read the references you posted.  I'm guessing I never tried this past about 1_42 as we're saddled with RHEL 6 where I work.