# boost spirit on_success handler for partial results

Tags: boost-spirit

The rule to parse something like "a.b.c" and "a().b"

```
postfix = 
     primary  [_val=_1] >> *(
                (lit('(') > paralistopt  > lit(')'))  [_val = construct<common_node>(type_cmd_fnc_call,key_this, construct<common_node>(_val), key_parameter, construct<std::vector<common_node> >(_1))]
              | (lit('.') > name_pure)                [_val = construct<common_node>(type_cmd_dot_call,key_this, construct<common_node>(_val), key_propname, construct<std::wstring>(_1))]
       )
    ;
```

The annotation code for the rule (common_node is the AST entry)

```
void annotateNode(parserDataS & data,const std::wstring::const_iterator & pos1, const std::wstring::const_iterator & pos2, common_node & node)
 {
   // calc pos
   int p1=std::distance(data.init_pos, pos1);
   int p2=std::distance(data.init_pos, pos2);
   // range is from  >=p1 <=p2
   node.makeLocation(std::make_pair(p1, p2-1));
 }
```

handler Setup

```
  on_success(postfix, phoenix::bind(&annotateNode, phoenix::ref(parserData),_1, _3,_val))
```

So far no problem, using "a.b" the annotation is called on the node.
But when using a.b.c.d the "on_success" is only called on the first node "a" for each member (b,c,d)
How to code the "on_succcess" for each member .. "a.b" "(a.b).c" "(a.b.c).d" separate ?

Answer (score 1):

You'd do better to just amend the semantic action to do the extra work, as you clearly intend. Otherwise, split out subrules (looks like you already have) and make the `on_success` handler run for those too.

If you need more help, I suggest posting a self-contained example. If you have trouble making one, perhaps you can build off the one I wrote in [boost::spirit access position iterator from semantic actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612657/boostspirit-access-position-iterator-from-semantic-actions/19613827#19613827)

Comment: Oh PS, if you're "just" looking for source location annotating tokens like `name_pure` you can have it automatic [with e.g. `string_ref`/`string_view`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47334796/85371) or a semantic-action approach like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358975/cross-platform-way-to-get-line-number-of-an-ini-file-where-given-option-was-foun/8365427#8365427